# Hybris how to cache components?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Currently in my project we are caching methods using ehcache and Spring cache system, however I don't know which mechanism we should use to cache components like header, footer, banners etc...

Does Hybris provides a mechanism via XML to cache these components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Hybris already caches CMS components using an EhCache region called `cmsCacheRegion`. You can find configuration for this bean in `acceleratorcms-cache-spring.xml`

This can be enabled/disabled with the property `cms.cache.enabled`. If using Cloud Commerce, this property will be enabled by default on storefront nodes.

If you would like to extend the CMS component types being cached, see bean `defaultCacheKeyProviders` in `acceleratorcms-spring.xml`. You should mostly be covered though as there's an entry for `AbstractCMSComponent`

Some more information here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/2105/en-US/8abd87cc866910149aa5e52e716d568e.html?q=acceleratorcms